# Any Android-based PDF+DJVU+EPUB reader with an option similar to High Contrast (Black)?

Tags: android, open-source, pdf-viewer, accessibility, djvu

I'm a visually impaired (i.e. partially sighted) person with some reading vision unless in direct sunlight, and that too only from a short distance of about six inches at most!

I'm a student of mathematics.

In order to read electronic books (ebooks), I use WinDjView for .djvu files, Adobe Acrobat Reader for .pdf files, and Epub Reader for .epub files on my Windows-based desktop PC.

I'm nowadays using Windows 8.1 on a Dell PC and have the High Contrast (Black) enabled.

In WinDjView and Adobe Acrobat Reader, I've also turned on the relevant settings so as to enable me to view my ebooks as white (or light-colored) text against a black (or dark-colored) background.

Without this sort of customization, I find viewing the computer screen extremely inconvenient.

In order to be able to read "on the go", I'm now looking for a device such as the Samsung's Galaxy Tab A (10.1'). Please visit the following URL for more information about this product.

https://www.samsung.com/pk/tablets/galaxy-tab-a10/#specs

However, I'm not aware of any Android-based DJVU+PDF+Epub reader software program that offers the High Contrast (Black) or a similar option. Is there any such program? Is there any free app with this feature? What about EbookDroid?

The reason why I'm not in favor of getting myself a laptop is the disadvantage for me while using a laptop because of the too close proximity of the screen with the keypad.

Comment: While I'm not aware of a reader meeting your requirements (I don't use DJVu, and have no needs for the contrast settings essential for you), I can offer you to check with my list of Android [eBook Readers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/reading_ebookreaders). I know several of them support DJVu – and with some luck, one of those also mentions the contrast settings in its description. Good luck!

Comment: @Izzy thank you for your comment, but the info available at the link you've given me is not very easy for me to navigate. So can you please pinpoint the exact software program amongst the ones mentioned such that the program not only allows access to DJVU+PDF+Epub but also supports High Contrast (Black) or a similar setting?

Comment: I can't. As I wrote, there are several apps supporting that in the list, but I don't know which one fits. Thinking about my suggestion (and seeing your comment), it's a catch-22 as indeed the list is hard to walk for you – apologies that I didn't consider that before commenting! // Maybe [PocketBook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.obreey.reader), [eBooka](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=droid.reader.book.epub.mobi.pdf.djvu.fb2.txt.azw.azw3), or [Librera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foobnix.pdf.reader) are good candidates?